# Convert python list to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python

I am doing a webapp on Google App Engine.

Now, I have a python list 'bb' of image link, and when I passed it to javascript, I got the error message `"Uncaught ReferenceError: bb is not defined"`.

So far, I have tried the following:

- `json.dumps(bb)` - didn't show any image at all with no error
- `array.array('c',bb)` - didn't show any image at all with no error

Any help? Thanks.

```
    <img id="output" src="" height="300" width="500" border="0" alt="image">
     <script>
      function loadImages(imgArr){
              for(var i=0; i< imgArr.length; i++) {
                   document.getElementById('output').src = imgArr[i];
              }
      }
      loadImages(bb);
     </script>
```

Comment: Where is bb defined? From your explanation bb seems to be a python object? Where do you pass it to javascript?

Comment: def post():
    bb = ['a','b']
    self.response.write(''' html javascript stuffs ''')

Comment: Yes, okay. That's the python part. But your error message simply says that bb is not defined in Javascript. So where do you create the variable bb in JavaScript?

Comment: I haven't. Can you show me how to link python list and javascript array?

Comment: Basically you need a URL which provides the JSON object. Then you have to retrieve that JSON object with JavaScript and iterate over its entries. Do you have that URL already?

Comment: I don't have it yet. I am pretty new to javascript to html.
Can you show me?

Comment: I know what you mean now. Thanks. Solved.

Comment: Great. I have added an answer, so maybe you could accept that...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your variable *bb* is only known in python. Hence you need to populate it to the JavaScript.

There is no direct conversion between JavaScript and Python. You will need to provide a URL to a python (web) service which serves a JSON object. This URL will be queried by a (a)synchronous JavaScript call. As a result of this call you get the JSON object in JavaScript. Voila!